# error: Relative import path "reflect-metadata" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../

Tags: es6-modules, deno

I'm trying to start making discord bots with Deno and TypeScript. I'm new to Deno and have no idea how to import packages. I tried a lot of things. But most of the time I get this error:

> error: Relative import path "reflect-metadata" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ from "https://unpkg.com/discordx@9.0.1/build/esm/index.js"
> at https://unpkg.com/discordx@9.0.1/build/esm/index.js:1:8

My current code is this:

```
import { Client } from "https://unpkg.com/discordx@9.0.1/build/esm";

const client: Client = new Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"],
});

console.log("done");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, but its readme states that it's essentially a wrapper around `discord.js` (which is authored for Node.js, and not for Deno). To learn about interoperability with Node.js module code, consult the relevant [manual section](https://deno.land/manual@v1.16.2/npm_nodejs).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where are you planning to host your hypothetical Discord bots running on Deno?

Comment: @jsejcksn custom server

Comment: @jsejcksn thank you I'll check it out

Comment: @jsejcksn I read it. Do you have any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: Now that you've read the docs, can you show us what you tried differently from your original post that still didn't work?

Comment: @jsejcksn I tried requiring discord.js in the same way but it was still the same error. I gut frustrated and ALT + F4 so I don't have it. But I have no idea what to do

Comment: I ended up testing this many different ways (as CJS and as ESM, using multiple recommended CDNs, installing the npm package directly, etc.) It seems that the package depends on the `https` node module, [which is not yet supported](https://deno.land/manual@v1.16.2/npm_nodejs/std_node#:~:text=Following%20modules%20are%20not%20yet%20implemented). So, for now, you'll have to use Node.js if you want to use a package that depends on `discord.js`.

Comment: @jsejcksn Well that's a shame. Thank you for the help so much though.